# EAFP and false catching of AttributeErrors

Tags: python

I am new to Python and the concepts behind.

Some days ago I followed EAFP without ever hearing of it:

```
try:
    self._parent.OptionalFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3)
except AttributeError:
    # self._parent does not have OptionalFunction, no problem
    pass
```

What happend was that while refactoring I changed `OptionalFunction` from getting 3 seperate objects to a list of objects and other stuff. I forgot to change one of the above blocks calling `OptionalFunction`, so I passed three arguments and my code in `OptionalFunction` tried to compute them and failed, raising and attribute error.
Because of the code block above that error never appeared as an error and I searched way to long for it.

So I changed all my code to code blocks like:

```
if hasattr(self._parent, "OptionalFunction"):
    self._parent.OptionalFunction(listOfArgs, otherArgs)
```

Today I learned about [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) and [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl), so I want to know how to prevent my issues while being "pythonic" in terms of using EAFP?

One solution I thought of was to catch AttributeErrors inside of `OptionalFunction` and raise a custom error, but this would blow up my function and I would have to think about this case in every function I write: "Will i use it with a EAFP in the future?"

So is there a neat way to handle this problem?

Comment: First version is better, but instead of 'pass' you should log the error.

Comment: I dont want to log because I am using this part of code on two applications, one without the optional function. Think of GUI vs Console SW: On _parent as GUI OptionalFunction would be the GUI update, not needed on console (so no error and no need to log something)

Comment: This distinct problem you had is prevented with more responsible refactoring and automated tests. Try/except blocks are more for run time exceptions, not for careless coding :}.

Comment: I know that and am in fact using Unit Testing for some part of my code (I'm writing C code in my main Job in the medical field so unit testing is part of my workflow). Was more concerned on how to handle the EAFP approach without catching the wrong exceptions. I could write `if type(self._parent) is GUIApplication:`, but that again seems unpythonic and more like LBYL.

Comment: Logging is for when things go wrong. It's ok to have a logging system in place and no errors.

Comment: It takes too much time for me to respond, we are dephased. You should catch all exceptions, right or wrong :}.

Comment: Okay, so we may be out of sync :/ No Problem, let's sync. I could try to catch the "unexpected" exception inside of OptionalFunction. I don't want that because error handling will be done inside a "higher level" code block. So I want to catch the Error by a nonexisting OptionalFunction (because I expect it and it's covered by EAFP). But I want any other Attribute error inside a 'EAFP'-TryExcept-Block to be raised and not catched. Do you have a example how to solve this? So I can catch the errors I produce (unintentionally ofc)?

Comment: To answer your question, in the except branch  you can check for the attribute error and re rise the exception if it's something else (see https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions).

Comment: But I think you may need to structure the two applications a bit differently. Don't call the function on console, or make a dummy function with that name or better let the gui app update itself when it needs.

Comment: To catch all the errors you can wrap the app in some function like app.run() and write a block try: app.run() except: logging.exception("").

Comment: I do explicit only catch an AttributeError, but also an AttributeError in the `OptionalFunction`. Restructuring is the only 'real' solution I see, but it will end in an 'if app is console' block, which seems to be seen as unpythonic by some members of the community. The last approach is my actual logging solution ;)

Comment: This is getting long, we can chat if you want. It shouldn't be with "if app is console" but each app importing the common stuff when need it and the gui app doing its thing when need it.